# Loading binary file from J2SE into iOS iphone using STL / POSIX

Tags: java, iphone, c++, ios

So i am trying to support some legacy tools i wrote a while back in Java for J2ME development.

I need to read in the same file formats in C++ on iphone/ipad. Before you ask why ->( as i need to also support Android NDK r7 )

Now i cant get the values to match and im sure i have it right: Here is my Java (J2SE) code:-

```
File file = new File(location, "test.d2r");

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

int i = Integer.reverseBytes(8);

writer.write(i);
writer.newLine();
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

And in iOS land im doing:-

```
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"d2r"];

FILE* fp = fopen([url UTF8String], "r");

if (fp) 
{
    int j;
    printf("\nReading...\n");

    fscanf(fp, "%c", &j);
    fclose(fp); 

    printf("DIGIT 1 %d\n\n", j);
}
else
{
    printf("\n\n No file found...... \n\n");
}
```

So the file opens fine but the numbers don't match up. Ive tried flipping the Endian over. The only thing i can consider is that as i am converting from an unsigned (java) platform to signed (c++) platform i am getting the sign in there and its messing up the value.

Unsure though, any pointers would be greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fscanf` is for reading text, not for reading binary data.

Instead of the `fscanf`, you should use `fread`:

```
fread(&j, 4, 1, fp);
```

Futhermore, you should open the file with the option "rb" instead of "r" to indicate that you want to read a binary file. Depending on the operation system, this can be essential.

This is correct and then this is the Java side:-

Ok so the mixture of Codo's answer on the C++ side and this is the write operation on the Java side

```
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(  
                  new FileOutputStream("bob_FontTool.d2r", false));

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());  
buffer.putInt(8);  
out.write(buffer.array());

out.flush();  
out.close();
```

Comment: Cheers, i was additionally loading a int* [] and ++ the pointer through it and getting the same numerical value, that fixes my c++ side but the number is incorrect so somewhere in the write the 4 bytes are in the wrong order or something.